# Haskell syntax: the meaning of {..} and @

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm just learning Yesod/Haskell.

In the following code (http://www.yesodweb.com/book/restful-content) there are two things I don't understand (and a subsequent question).

1. `{..}` - what does that mean?  (It's a hard term to google for.)
2. `person@Person` - what does the `@` sign do?
3. Is there a way I can find answers to ungooglable Haskell syntax, without bothering you all on StackOverflow?

code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies      #-}
import           Data.Text (Text)
import           Yesod

data Person = Person
    { name :: Text
    , age  :: Int
    }

instance ToJSON Person where
    toJSON Person {..} = object
        [ "name" .= name
        , "age"  .= age
        ]

data App = App

mkYesod "App" [parseRoutes|
/ HomeR GET
|]

instance Yesod App

getHomeR :: Handler TypedContent
getHomeR = selectRep $ do
    provideRep $ return
        [shamlet|
            <p>Hello, my name is #{name} and I am #{age} years old.
        |]
    provideJson person
  where
    person@Person {..} = Person "Michael" 28

main :: IO ()
main = warp 3000 App
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For points 1 and 2, I guess you're referring to line

```
person@Person {..}
```

The `{..}` comes from the [`RecordWildcards`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#record-wildcards) extension. Basically it brings in scope all fields of the `Person` datatype. That's why you can use `name` and `age` in the Hamlet template above.

The `@` serves as an alias. Everytime you see `id@deconstructor_expr` you can use `id` for the entire value which is deconstructed by `deconstructor_expr`. For example you can have

```
f (x:a@(y:_)) = a
```

and `a` will be the `tail` of the argument list as long as the list has at least 2 elements (that is `f` is `tail` for lists with more than 2 elements).

Without these two, the entire function would have to change to

```
getHomeR :: Handler TypedContent
getHomeR = selectRep $ do
    provideRep $ return
        [shamlet|
            <p>Hello, my name is #{name'} and I am #{age'} years old.
        |]
    provideJson person
  where
    person = Person "Michael" 28
    name' = name person
    age' = age person
```

Observe that `name` and `age` are functions from the record to the specific field and that means that you have to use other names for the values (the `'`-ending variables). Also, because we no longer use `@` we need separate lines for the `person` and for the fields.

Another alternative would be

```
getHomeR :: Handler TypedContent
getHomeR = selectRep $ do
    provideRep $ return
        [shamlet|
            <p>Hello, my name is #{name person} and I am #{age person} years old.
        |]
    provideJson person
  where
    person = Person "Michael" 28
```

You still need to call the `name` and `age` functions.

For point 3, a possibility is to go on IRC on #haskell and ask there. Anyway, the same people from there are here, it's not a bother in asking.

Comment: So `person@Person {..} = Person "Michael" 28` could have been replaced with `name = "Michael"`, `age = 28` and `person = Person name age`?

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that `name` and `age` are the names of functions of `Person`, so you need new identifiers.

Answer (score 7):

Adding to other answers, for searching for ungooglable syntax use [symbolhound.com](http://symbolhound.com/).

Answer (score 2):

`{..}` unpacks a record into variables. In your case it defines `name` and `age`. `@` takes the entire value in a pattern match, so in `person@Person {..}`, `person` would be the original `Person` value.